# Как передать значение из контроллера в класс?

Tags: c#, mvc

В HomeController есть Post-метод

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SelectionSiteId(string SelectedSiteId)
    {
        SelectedId = SelectedSiteId;


        return View("Index");
    }
```

SelectedId - переменная тип string, ее значение надо передать в класс UserService. Подскажите как это сделать

Comment: А где у вас класс UserService? Вы его передали на конструктор контроллера? Или хотите вызвать через `var result = new  UserService(SelectedSiteId);`?

Comment: @AK User Service в другой папке. Мне нужно ему передать значение Selected Id, чтобы присвоить его одной из переменных